# Por que o Stylus não está identificando classes?

Tags: css, preprocessador, stylus

Estou com um problema com o Stylus. Compilando meu código pelo Node as vezes ele dá um *bug*, parece que ele não identifica as classes por causa do `.` gerando o seguinte erro:

> expected "indent", got "outdent"

Obs: Tem horas que funciona e tem horas que não.

```
header h1
    font-weight: 500
    margin-bottom: -1em

input, label
    column(12)

input, select
    margin: 0.5em auto 1em auto
    height: 1.8em
    border: solid #ccc 0.1em

button
    margin: 1em
    background-color: ##205FBE
    color: white

.txt-center
    text-align: center
```

Comment: O meu problema não é esse, eu não estou nomeando uma variável ou um mixin com '.', eu só quero usar uma classe...

Comment: Já verificaste se realmente não há espaços indentados, ou já experimentaste usar hífen em vez de pontos  ?

Comment: Testa indentar e remover os espaços, use o `sublime-text` para isso. Aperte crt + shift + p e digite `Indentation: Convert to Spaces` , isso sempre me ajuda com Stylus e também com Jade

Comment: Valeu @RubensBarbosa funcionou!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que estava fazendo ele retornar o erro é que existia um espaço no meio dos tabs.

Como eu uso sublime text, usei a dica do @Rubens Barbosa, acessei o command palette (ctrl+shift+p):

> "Indentation: Convert to Spaces"

E depois converti para tabs novamente.

> "Indentation: Convert to Tabs"

Agora vou me policiar para usar sempre o tab. Pelo que percebi, em outros testes que fiz, o `Stylus` é bem sensível com relação a erros no código. Nem sempre onde ele aponta é onde o problema está, vale a pena dar uma revisada no código.

Obrigada pela ajuda pessoal

Comment: Use o link de edição em sua pergunta para adicionar outras informações. O botão Publicar resposta deve ser usado apenas para concluir respostas à pergunta. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/49051)

Comment: @Otto, *é uma resposta*, pode ser pobre, mal-explicada, mas é uma resposta; votar para deletar não é o adequado. . . . . Clara, o ideal é você colocar a solução tal como sugeriu o Rubens Barbosa (dando o devido crédito)

Comment: Desculpa pessoal, já editei minha resposta.